# Accidentally formatted boot from my Tablet Hisense Sero 7 Lite

Tags: android

I accidentally fromatted the boot of my Hisense Tablet Sero 7 Lite, now my devise can't load android, it boot with the recovery mode. I have CWM-based V6.0.3.1.

Can you tell me please what it the steps that i have to follow to fix this problem, i am new with tablets and it's my first problem.

Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Before continuing you must have **CWM** installed.

Ok this is the download [Link here](https://drive.google.com/?usp=folder&authuser=0#folders/0B0qWajm06CvhWE5pTERaR1BFRmM)

1. Create a folder in your external sd card called "clockworkmod"
   then create another folder inside the clockworkmod folder called
   "backup" and then extract the file downloaded ( the backup of stock
   rom) an put the folder "2014-01-01.17.10.03" inside the backup
   folder.
2. Instert your sd on the sero 7 lt and boot it in recovery mode
   then Do a wipe data factory reset, then go to mounts and storage,
   format system, go back and go to the backup and restore option and
   select restore from external sd card, then select the
   "2014-01-01.17.10.03" option , and select yes.
3. Select the reboot system now option if it ask something hit yes.

Once this is done. Enjoy your un-softbricked device.